# How can I delete a folder from the firebase storage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I attempted to accomplish this with the bellow function. But the issue is that for some reason doing this causes `thumbRef.delete {` to not run. Instead, it just loops forever.

**How can I make this work?**

**Note:** I want to delete all contents within a folder. If I could delete the entire folder I would.

```
private var done = false

private func deletePostFromStorage(selectedPost: Post) {
    let postID = selectedPost.media.postID
    let uid = selectedPost.user.userID
    print(postID, " tytytytyty ", uid)

    // Create a reference to the file to delete
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(uid!).child(postID!)
    var i = 1
    while !done {
        let thumbRef = storageRef.child("media\(i).jpg")
        let vidRef2 = storageRef.child("media\(i).mov")
        let imageRef3 = storageRef.child("media\(i)")

        print(done, " INSIDE THE WHILE LOOP ", i)
        // Delete the file
        thumbRef.delete { error in
            print("fhdjskfhdsakjfhkadsl")

            if let error = error {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                print("thumb error in delete")
                imageRef3.delete(completion: { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        //error occured no more medias (no vid no image and no thumbnail with this media)
                        self.done = true
                        print("image error in delete")
                    } else {
                        //successfull deletion
                        print("image deleted")
                    }
                })
            } else {
                print("thumb delete succes")

                // File deleted successfully
                vidRef2.delete(completion: { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        //error occured
                        print("video error in delete")
                    } else {
                        //successfull deletion
                        print("video deleted")
                    }
                })
            }

            if i > 30 {
                //this is only for testing make sure its not endless
                self.done = true
            }
        }
        i+=1
    }
}
```

I am also experimenting with this function in the backend:

```
    function deletePostFromStorage(uid: string, postID: string) {
  const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    //const bucket = gcs.bucket(functions.config().firebase.storageBucket);
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    return bucket.deleteFiles({
      prefix: `${uid}/${postID}/`
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(`All the Firebase Storage files in ${uid}/${postID}/ have been deleted`);
      }
    });
}
```

But I get errors like:

```
    ERROR: /Users/=/Desktop/FinalAppPrjv2/firefunctions/functions/src/index.ts:205:23 - Module '@google-cloud/storage' is not listed as dependency in package.json
ERROR: /Users/=/Desktop/FinalAppPrjv2/firefunctions/functions/src/index.ts:206:9 - Shadowed name: 'functions'
ERROR: /Users/=/Desktop/FinalAppPrjv2/firefunctions/functions/src/index.ts:211:12 - Expression has type `void`. Put it on its own line as a statement.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work using this backend fucntion:

```
    function deletePostFromStorage(uid: string, postID: string) {
  //const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
  //const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    //const bucket = gcs.bucket(functions.config().firebase.storageBucket);
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    bucket.deleteFiles({
      prefix: `${uid}/${postID}/`
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(`All the Firebase Storage files in ${uid}/${postID}/ have been deleted`);
      }
    });
}
```